# jQuery - Search an array of objects to filter by property of object

Tags: jquery

I have an array of objects, see below:

```
var orderbyColumns = [Object { Descending=true, TableName="Users", ColumnName="RankCode", more...}, Object { Descending=false, TableName="Users", ColumnName="LastName", more...}]
```

Now I want to extract from orderbyColumns by the TableName and ColumnName properties.

It would be nice if the below worked, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
var filter = $(orderbyColumns).find('[ColumnName=' + columnName + ']');
```

It would be nice if you could do:

```
var filter = from x in orderbyColumns where x.TableName == "Users" && x.ColumnName == "RankCode" select x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might do it this way:

```
var orderByColumns = [ { Descending:true, TableName:"Users", ColumnName:"RankCode", more:"..."},  { Descending:false, TableName:"Users", ColumnName:"LastName", more:"..."}]
orderByColumns.findObject = findObject; 

var filter = orderByColumns.findObject("ColumnName","LastName");
alert(filter.Descending); // returns 'false'

function findObject(name,val) {
    var len = this.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (this[i][name]===val) { return this[i]; }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That was close enough for me to change it to: function findObjectByTableColumnName(table, column) {
    var len = this.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (this[i]["TableName"] === table && this[i]["ColumnName"] === column) {
            console.log(table + " -- " + column);
            return this[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Comment: Glad I could help -- don't forget to accept your favorite answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at linqjs -

http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

That should bring you closer to your nice to have query.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, but how is the equivalent done in jQuery? Without the plugin.